# Do App Engine datastore queries have a default sort order?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a default sort order for the returned values of App Engine datastore queries? If so what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you get key order, and key order depends on whether you took the default id or supplied a key name, and if the former, whether you used the default policy for key allocation. [The doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities) says "the default policy generates a random sequence of IDs that are approximately uniformly distributed. Each ID can be up to 16 decimal digits long."

The "16 digit" part is interesting. Basically, keys are 53 bits--the fraction part of an IEEE double. JavaScript uses IEEE doubles, so 53 bits is the largest integer value that you can safely round-trip through JSON.

Comment: So default sort order `Person.all()` is equivalent to `Person.all().order('__key__')` in Python where `Person` is an entity?

Comment: That's my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

[Datastore write costs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities%23Python_Understanding_write_costs) says datastore entity includes built-in `EntityByKinds` index. [This index](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown%23anc-entitiesbykind) includes entity key.

> Every time a new entity of any kind is added, a new row is automatically added to this table with the new entity's key so it can be queried later.

So I guess if no order provided, datastore returns entities ordered by key.

> The entity key is stored so the entity itself can be efficiently retrieved if it's returned as a result for the executed query.

I could not find document about asc/desc, but when I queried below, default order was `asc`.

```
>SELECT * FROM Model order by __key__ asc
>SELECT * FROM Model
success and same result
>SELECT * FROM Model order by __key__ desc
no matching index found
```

So conclusion of my research is that default order is

```
order by __key__ asc
```

Please correct me if I miss something.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on which parameter you filter on. Basically the sort order is always ASC, depending on how it's filtered. Take a look at [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities) it might help.  Basically whichever filter you use will determine the sort order.  Another interesting doc would be [this one](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes) which explains indexes in more details.

In the event you don't use a filter, I do believe the index used is the index based on the keys, so you'd have an ascending key as your order.

Comment: What if you don't use a filter?

Comment: Edited the answer to add it, even if other people already answered it :)

Comment: Thanks. From the other answers it looks like the default sort order is always ascending, not descending.

Comment: WOW, you're totally right. I dunno why I got them mixed out. I will edit to reflect that, to make sure the answer is actually valid. Thx for pointing it out (I dunno why I was convinced it was desc)